# reddit app on search click animation - how to?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am not sure if it is a transition or an animation, however, when you click on the search of the [reddit app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.reddit.frontpage&hl=en), the app's search activity's **Visibility** slides over its main activity.

I want to achieve that animation. Thank You

Comment: I removed the image, I don't think I have to explain why.

Comment: I am actually quite new to stack. Is this a rule I need to know? Thanks

Comment: Not sure why this isn't obvious, but nsfw content is a big no